# How to add some lines to the wp-login.php header via functions.php?

Tags: headers

I have no idea what function to use to add this line to the wp-login.php header:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">`

I have tried `add_action('wp_head', 'change_this_name_of_your_function');` until I have found out that the `wp-login.php` file uses a different header. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_head` is for adding stuff in the `head` of the public/non-admin side of a WordPress site. For the standard login page for the admin screens, you can use [`login_head`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_head/):

```php
add_action( 'login_head', function () {
    echo '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">';
} );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I really need to improve my Google skills!